# How to send cross origin SOAP request using java script / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, web-services, soap

My python script to access a SOAP web service.

Here I am consuming  HTTPS web-service using unverified SSL context, So it won't show any errors in certificate errors.

Now I want to achieve the same with JavaScript.I am trying with this [Jquery SOAP library](https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap).

My Python snippet:

```
import suds
import ssl
import os
import cookielib


if hasattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context'):
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

client = suds.client.Client("https://192.168.1.2:3455/mysoap")
login = client.service.login("root","password")
```

What is the equivalent snippet /code sample in javaScript..?

Comment: Is the webservice setting CORS headers? If not you are going to need to proxy it.

Comment: not sure about CORS , I got this when sending a js request "net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE"